# Want to update changes in localserver to live server

Tags: reactjs, node.js, nginx, pm2, vps

I want a solution of vps server i already setup my vps and deployed my react.js web appliction on it.Now i want to update my changes to live server but i can't update my project on live server . The method i used for deployed my web application to the live server is Putty. I installed nginx and pm2 for start and reboot purpose on my vps server and already cloned my project through github.But now i want to make some changes on live server.First it will change it to the local server and then i want to make changes on live server.Will you please tell me what's the solution to do that thing. I created a directory from live server called react-application and inside the directory i upload the web application.The domain is not connected on the live server because i didn't purchase a domain yet. I directly deployed on webserver and to want to see my web application i use the ip addreess.

I already installed modules which is necessary for vps like ngnix and pm2,and i have pushed my code to the main repo but it updates the main repo but not update on live server the changes i made from local server is applied but not on the vps.

Comment: You have to send the files again

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ftp access try [ftp-simple](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humy2833.ftp-simple) extension with vs code to connect your live server and make changes in files remotely.

Comment: is there any extension needed in visual code because i,don't want to use putty again and again for authentication,Will you please suggest me if any other option available like most of extensions are present in vs code but i don't have familirize with them.If you have any idea that will help me out of this problem ,then please tell me.

Comment: As asked do you have ftp, sftp access on your remote server? did you tried ftp-simple extension with vs code?

Comment: yes i have access to my remote server using putty .

Comment: I tried to access my remote server using ftp-simple extension in vs code,but still the changes are not applied to my vps , what should i do now ? I already pushed it to my github repo,but still it's nothing changes on my vps.